# Can u help me: Yahoo 11.0.0.2014 will not install on Windows 8 Toshiba Laptop

Tags: windows-8, compatibility

I have a HP NX-9600 that the hard drive went bad in but I managed to make an ISO image of that drive. I've ordered and received a replacement drive and hope to restore that 'puter mostly for archival purposes.

In the meantime I purchased a Toshiba P875-S7102 Windows 8 machine. At present, version 11.0.0.2014 will load and run occasionally. But, often I get the error: 'a script on this page has quit running' and it refuses to finish loading. I am running on the Windows8 machine from an 'extracted copy' of the previous laptop's drive.

Is there a way to make it run on Windows 8, once I restore the original laptop? Or pull it the program) out once I have no further need of the extracted copy?

Wayne

Comment: Which program are you referring to when you say Yahoo a.b.c.d? You should be specific when asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google says that the version of Yahoo Messenger you are using is out of date.  I would uninstall what you have and download the latest version from [messenger.yahoo.com](http://messenger.yahoo.com/) and try installing that.

Comment: I tried that already it won't install. it isn't even recognized as a downloaded file.